# Can I READ from ethereum as a before hook on my HTTP request?

Tags: blockchain

I want to add user authentication using ethereum. Let's say I have a User contract that maps a users phones UDID to an account ID

Let's say I have one existing record for "user1" -> "device1".

On my node server is there a way to authenticate that the user matches with the account id before every request? Would READing from the ethereum blockchain be super slow and therefore make this a bad idea? How long does it generally take to READ from the blockchain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to read from the blockchain, you would need a way to connect to it.  If you're creating a web app, you would need a web3 provider, which is a blockchain node that you run yourself (in the true spirit of the decentralized blockchain) or you could connect to third party providers (e.g. Infura).

Once you have a connection to the blockchain, reading is pretty quick because basically you would be retrieving the data from that blockchain node / web3 provider, which should be syncing to the blockchain real-time.  So reading from it is just like a database call.

(Note: if the node has been disconnected for a while, and it needs to sync, then this may take some time; if you're creating your own node, then this could take a really long time to sync for the first time, even a few days).

You could use create a contract to store your mappings (user => device).  But note, that all data stored on the blockchain is public. So anyone can access it.  So if you want to do this, you would need to figure out a way to do encryption "offchain" and store only encrypted data on the blockchain.